# Extjs 4: Create an iFrame Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am in need of creating an iFrame Window in Extjs. Previously in ExtJS 3.x I would do this:

```
bodyCfg: {
    tag: 'iframe'
}
```

But the `Window` Class of ExtJS 4 seems not to have a bodyCfg.

Any ideas on how to make an iFrame ExtJS 4 Window?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think `autoEl` is what you are looking for...

Some advice from me, in Ext 4.x don't use `autoEl` as a `window` config property, it can make your window malformed.. I suggest you to use `autoEl` in a `component` (items of your window)

```
new Ext.Window({
    title : "iframe",
    width : 300,
    height: 300,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{
        xtype : "component",
        autoEl : {
            tag : "iframe",
            src : "http://www.yahoo.com"
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

The code above is better than

```
new Ext.Window({
    title : "iframe",
    width : 300,
    height: 300,
    layout : 'fit',
    autoEl : {
       tag : "iframe",
       src : "http://www.yahoo.com"
    }
}).show();
```

Note: currenty you can't load Google and Facebook inside an iframe

Comment: In case you want to change the iframe src dynamically, call the following code through your srcUpdate function: `Ext.getDom('iframe-win').src = "http://www.yahoo.com";`

Comment: It is important with 4.2 to use "component" (as shown above) instead of "container", although why I do not know.  `"container"` will fail to grow/shrink and will throw an error about calling setstyle on null.

Comment: Refused to display 'https://www.yahoo.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: I have no idea why, but ours refused to work with `src`.  So, we instead used `html: '<iframe src="http://example.com" width="100% height="100%"></iframe>` and it worked great.